# How to pass block if current thread is same

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, thread-safety, dispatch-queue

I have write a class to handle `DispatchQueues`. I have write a static method to invoke `main` thread. I pass a `completionHandler` as an argument and current just accessing the main thread and call this completion handler inside the main thread block. This cause hanging when this method is called several time concurrently so I want to check if method is already invoked by a main thread then I shouldn't dispatch a queue rather than I just call the completion handler but when I call this `completionHandler` it goes into some other thread but not as main thread.

**Here is my class**

```
class ETQueue: NSObject {
    static func main(completion: @escaping()->()) {
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            // If current thread is main the i am calling the completion handler but execution of this completionHandler
            //Takes the thread to some other level.
            completion()
        }else {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
    static func main(_ deley: Double, completion: @escaping()->()) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + deley) {
            completion()
        }
    }
    static func background(completion: @escaping()->()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternate way for what you want to achieve. For this first, you need to send it on a background thread and then dispatch again on the main thread.

```
class ETQueue: NSObject {
    static func main(completion: @escaping()->()) {
        ETQueue.background {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
    static func main(_ deley: Double, completion: @escaping()->()) {
        ETQueue.background {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + deley) {
                completion()
            }
        }
    }
    static func background(completion: @escaping()->()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow this solution worked... This is kinda tricky but an easy approach.